# Calculating CPI

Tags: macroeconomics

The question is [image]

I know how to calculate CPI in the sense without " a basket of 700 goods and services". How does adding this info change my calculation? I only know CPI= (the price of basket of goods in a year/ price of basket in a base year)X100. So in 2010, it will be ((2x5)/7)X100=100.

Thank you for your answer. I've just begun self-taught economics.

Answer (score 2):

The next sentence of the question instructs you to ignore the "700 goods and services" and focus only on meat and movie tickets.